# Ranking by specific percentile

Tags: quantiles, ranking, ranks

Is there a name for ranking categories by their value in a specific percentile (e.g., 66th percentile)?

**A fictitious example**:

*Goethe* published 9 books, *Schiller* published 7, and *Herder* published 3.

We now rank these books by the number of times they were cited:

| Goethe | Schiller | Herder |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 972 | 766 | 40 * |
| 718 | 720 * | 27 |
| 248 * | 512 | 22 |
| 241 | 461 |  |
| 150 | 37 |  |
| 83 | 22 |  |
| 17 | 4 |  |
| 0 |  |  |
| 0 |  |  |

I put an asterisk `*` at each column's 66th percentile value (hope I got that right...). Extracting them leads to this ranking:

| Rank | Author | citation count in 33rd percentile |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Schiller | 720 |
| 2 | Goethe | 248 |
| 3 | Herder | 40 |

This final table is supposed to serve as a new ranking between Schiller, Goethe and Herder (Schiller is ranked #1, Goethe #2, Herder #3).

I would like to know how this ranking-approach is called (so that I can find discussions about implementations, pros/cons etc.) - - your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: It's unclear what you even mean by "approach:" how do you intend to use the results in your bottom table?

Comment: @whuber, I added a sentence explaining that the final table is supposed to serve as a new ranking (according to which Schiller is #1).

Comment: Just putting objects in some kind of order is trivial.  What matters to you is *how you will use this ranking* for any further decisions or analyses.  That will suggest how to evaluate the goodness of rankings and can help justify (or debunk) the 33rd percentile approach.

Answer (score 2):

When you have so few observations in a set of observations (9 for Goethe, 7 for Schiller, and 3 for Herder), there are different methods to determine quantiles.  For example, in R you can choose any of 7 methods. ( [www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/quantile](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/quantile) .)

Usually observations are listed from smallest to greatest for identifying quantiles, so I think you are looking for the 66.7 th percentile or the 0.667 quantile.

You can play with the different methods of calculating quantiles in R, with the `type` option in the `quantile()` function by running the following code in R or at  https://rdrr.io/snippets/.

I've never heard of any name for such a ranking technique, except to say that the groups were ranked by the 66.7 th percentile of their observations.

```
Goethe   = c(972,718,248,241,150,83,17,0,0)
Schiller = c(766,720,512,461,37,22,4)
Herder   = c(40,27,22)

summary(Goethe)
summary(Schiller)
summary(Herder)

sum(Goethe)
sum(Schiller)
sum(Herder)

quantile(Goethe,   0.667, type = 7)
quantile(Schiller, 0.667, type = 7)
quantile(Herder,   0.667, type = 7)
```